# Redirect 301 clarification

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've done a fairly standard 301 redirect from [www.olddom.com](http://www.olddom.com) to www.newdom.com.. and for whatever reason google change of address tool doesn't like it - which has sent me down a rabbit hole on the rewrite rules and noticed almost every blog I read has a slightly different way of writing it.

Please can somebody confirm the rewrite code needed for .htaccess when it must include the following 2 things:

1. Forward all domain variants (http://olddom.com, https://olddom.com, http://www.olddom.com and https://www.olddom.com) to https://www.newdom.com)
2. Keep URL location (olddom.com/about gets forwarded to https://www.newdom.com/about).

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your tried htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "olddomain.co.uk$"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^/"
RewriteRule ".*" "https://www.newdomain.co.uk/" [L,R=301]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^olddomain-co-uk[.]"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^/"
RewriteRule ".*" "https://www.newdomain.co.uk/" [L,R=301]